# 'ToPILImage' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pytorch

I'm doing an image processing task and I want to concat two sites of pictures. For concatting, I first converted the image to tensor, then converted the tensor to a PIL image to display it, but it was reported incorrectly.Could someone please help me?
Here is my code:

```
import skimage.io as io
import torch
from torchvision import  models, transforms
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision.transforms import ToPILImage
import numpy as np
from skimage import data_dir,io,color

coll1 = io.ImageCollection('F:\\code1/*.jpg')
coll2 = io.ImageCollection('F:\\code2/*.jpg')
a = torch.tensor(coll1)
print(a)
print(a.shape)
b = torch.tensor(coll2)
print(b)
print(b.shape)
c=torch.cat((a,b),1)
print(c.shape)
print(c)
img= transforms.ToPILImage()
img.show()
```

and here is the error code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:/filelist.py", line 39,
>   in 
>       img.show() AttributeError: 'ToPILImage' object has no attribute 'show'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ToPILImage` method accepts a tensor or an ndarray as input, [source](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage).

You will need to cast a single image tensor to the `ToPILImage` method. From your post, I suspect you are passing batches of image tensor instead of one, hence the error.

Assumed if you want to visualize image from tensor `c`,

```
img = transforms.ToPILImage()(c)
img.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried your method, but once again, I was given an error.And the error code is:TypeError: pic should be Tensor or ndarray. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.

Comment: Yeah I tried your new answer and it said:TypeError: pic should be Tensor or ndarray. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>.Thanks for your help,but I still do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you print the shape of tensor. I suspect that you are attempting to transform image batches instead of an image.

Comment: Yes ,you're right.I want to stitch up a total of 36 224*224 images in two folders and then enter them as a deep learning data set.But I don't know clearly how to do it.a is torch.Size([18, 224, 224, 3])，b is torch.Size([18, 224, 224, 3]),c is torch.Size([18, 448, 224, 3]).

Comment: What you need is a custom Dataset class. You can define your own Dataset class and in the `__getitem__` method, let the single image tensor go through the transform method. You can learn more [here](https://www.kaggle.com/pinocookie/pytorch-dataset-and-dataloader). Please accept my answer if it is useful :)

Comment: Thank you very much,your answer is of great help. Could you please give me your email or other contact information so I can ask for advice when I have questions about this problem.

Comment: SO is a great place for developers to help each other out. There are far more experienced developers than I am here ;)

Comment: I‘m sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "SO".Do you mean here,the "stack overflow"?

Comment: @Betty Stack overflow.